# react.js: Invalid hook call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React by making a motor cycle spec searching web application, and I am trying to import fetched data into `makePicker.jsx` to essentially make a drop down menu with those data.

However I am getting an error message saying:

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
> This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

I am not sure  what applies to my situation. Can you see why?

makePicker.jsx

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {NativeSelect, FormControl} from '@material-ui/core';
import styles from './makePicker.module.css';
import { makeList } from '../../api';

const MakePicker = ()=>{

  const [fetchedMakes, setFetchedMakes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchAPI = async()=>{
      setFetchedMakes(await makeList());
    }
    fetchAPI();
  },[])

  return (
    <h1>makePicker</h1>
  );

}

export default MakePicker;
```

App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {fetchData, makeList} from './api/index';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import MakePicker from './components/makePicker/makePicker';

class App extends React.Component{
  state = {

    data:[],
    makes:[],
  }

  async componentDidMount(){
//    const fetchedData = await fetchData();
    const fetchedMakeList = await makeList();
    this.setState({makes:fetchedMakeList});
  
    
  }


render(){
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
      {MakePicker()};
      <h1>Some line-ups from YAMAHA</h1>
      {this.state.makes.map(make=>{
        return <p>{make.name}</p>
      })}
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Open React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

}
  
export default App;
```

Please let me know if need more information from my project.

Comment: The code provided does not throw that error.

Comment: How did you call `MakePicker` in another component?

Comment: I agree with the commenters above: we need to see the other files because this code won't produce any hooks errors. Just guessing: are you using hooks in your API route? Because that will throw an error

Comment: This happens when you use Hooks outside jsx component.
This answer can be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62077729/is-it-possible-to-use-react-hooks-outside-of-functional-component-or-i-have-to

Comment: `MakePicker` is a component; not the function.  So instead of `{MakePicker()};` define as JSX element i.e. `<MakePicker />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code in `App.jsx` and following the naming convention of React's component, you should import it with the first-capitalized-letter name like below

```
import MakePicker from './components/makePicker/makePicker';
```

You're also calling `{makePicker()};` which is not a proper way for component rendering. You should modify it to

```
<MakePicker/>
```

Full possible change can be

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {fetchData, makeList} from './api/index';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import MakePicker from './components/makePicker/makePicker';

class App extends React.Component{
  state = {

    data:[],
    makes:[],
  }

  async componentDidMount(){
//    const fetchedData = await fetchData();
    const fetchedMakeList = await makeList();
    this.setState({makes:fetchedMakeList});
  
    
  }


render(){
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
      <MakePicker/>
      <h1>Some line-ups from YAMAHA</h1>
      {this.state.makes.map(make=>{
        return <p>{make.name}</p>
      })}
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Open React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

}
  
export default App;
```

To elaborate more why you get this error

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

When you call `makePicker()`, it's actually triggering a Javascript's function (not React's component as you expected), but `useEffect` is only available in React's components. That's why when you try to run code, the compiler is thinking `makePicker` is calling `useEffect` invalidly.

Answer (score 1):

Their is a problem lies on your useEffect

update the code like this and try it out:

```
 const fetchAPI = async()=>{
      const res = await makeList().then((data) => {
          setFetchedMakes(data)
       }).catch((err) => console.log(err))

 }
 useEffect(()=>{
    fetchAPI();
  },[])
```

here i placed the asynchronous function outside of the useEffect

Also make MakePicker as an JSX element like this: `<MakePicker />`